# Generics in Typescript cause unexpected error

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The following code:

```
export type Mixin<T extends any, Y extends string> = { [P in keyof T & string as `${Y}_${P}`]: T[P] };
```

Was compiled to the following compiled code:

```
export declare type Mixin<T extends any, Y extends string> = {
    [P in keyof T & string as `${Y}_${P}`]: T[P];
};
```

Causing this:

```
D:/Projects/testcafe-playground/node_modules/redis-modules-sdk/lib/modules/redis.d.ts (46, 28): ']' expected.
D:/Projects/testcafe-playground/node_modules/redis-modules-sdk/lib/modules/redis.d.ts (46, 42): ';' expected.
D:/Projects/testcafe-playground/node_modules/redis-modules-sdk/lib/modules/redis.d.ts (46, 43): Declaration or statement expected.
D:/Projects/testcafe-playground/node_modules/redis-modules-sdk/lib/modules/redis.d.ts (47, 1): Declaration or statement expected.
```

Anyone has a clue what is the reason? can't seem to find a fix

Comment: TS can really go nuts but i cannot recognize this part as valid: ``${Y}_${P}``

Comment: Can you explain more? What is compiling the type? Typically types are not present in compiled typescript. Also, the syntax of both types works fine in the playground https://tsplay.dev/mA7aQw

Comment: @LuisFilipe Then maybe you can help me do what I want more correctly. I have a type that contains functions, and I want to rename them from P to Y_P as a text. This thing works perfectly fine, but when used in as a module (being compiled) it goes nuts..

Comment: @AlexWayne It works fine for me to, but when compiled and then used in TestCafe for i.e. (Automation framework) it throws this err because it can't use this properly. For more info refer my comment to Luis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to dynamically define the properties (meaning defining the JS code) and in additional I had to manually define the TS properties with the type of the actual functions I want to defined "dynamically" so it's a dynamic static solution but that's all I found.
The code can be found here: https://github.com/danitseitlin/redis-modules-sdk/blob/master/modules/redis.ts